# Kotlin call Java platform types result in llegalStateException

Tags: android, exception, kotlin, stack-trace

I'm using `kotlin` in one of my Android classes and it seems like an `IllegalStateException` sometimes pops up on this line, when trying to get an extra from a `Bundle`.

```
keyOrTag = bundle.getString("tag")
```

And the `val` is declared like this

```
val keyOrTag: String
```

Unfortunately I don't have the full stack trace as I've noticed this from the GP Console.

Answer (score 4):

Okay I believe I know why that happens. Posting it as an answer so that others with a related issue could see.

The `String "tag"` added to the bundle can actually be `null` in the Java class that sends it over to the `Kotlin` one. And since I didn't declare the `val` as nullable I believe that's why it's throwing an IllegalStateException (yup, no NPE in kotlin).

The fix:

```
val keyOrTag: String?
```

Comment: matter of fact, shouldn't it be
`var  keyOrTag: String? = null` ? vals are final variables and therefore could only be initialized either via constructor or in place.

Comment: @k0sh well if I initialize it with `null` I won't be able to give it the value from the `Bundle`. And I only need that variable to have one value. Isn't that approach correct?

Comment: This is actually `Kotlin` issue that should show the error in compilation time instead of runtime, as `bundle.getString()` method can return potentially `null`, hope the owners of `Kotlin` fix this issue soon

Comment: @AlexNewman val variables should be initialized  either via constructor or in line, look at `val simple: Int? // has type Int, default getter, must be initialized in constructor` and https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html 

I'm not sure how the above doesn't yell with an error unless if you passing the Bundle to the constructor then it should be fine, but i'm not sure because I can't see your code.

Comment: @k0sh oh very sorry didn't provide enough context. I'm declaring that variable inside a function, not globally. And initializing it in the same function.

Comment: @AlexNewman well that makes sense now :) thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 4):

> **When** this error occurs?

The `IllegalStateException` was thrown by Kotlin [kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/cfe159181d27d6bd085993d0ad70694a64081cd9/core/runtime.jvm/src/kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics.java) possibly when you calling Java platform types.

> **Why** did you can't see the stackTrace of an `Exception` throws by [kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/cfe159181d27d6bd085993d0ad70694a64081cd9/core/runtime.jvm/src/kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics.java) from Kotlin?

This is because the `stackTrace` is removed by Kotlin in [Intrinsics#sanitizeStackTrace](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/cfe159181d27d6bd085993d0ad70694a64081cd9/core/runtime.jvm/src/kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics.java#L248) method internally:

```
private static <T extends Throwable> T sanitizeStackTrace(T throwable) {
    return sanitizeStackTrace(throwable, Intrinsics.class.getName());
}
```

### Example

Here is a Java platform type `StringUtils` source code, and the `toNull` method will return `null` if the parameter `value` is `null` or `""`.

```
public class StringUtils {
    public static String toNull(String value) {
        return value == null || value.isEmpty() ? null : value;
    }
}
```

**Then** you try to assign the result of the method call to a **non-nullable** variable possibly throws an `IllegalStateException`, for example:

```
val value: String = StringUtils.toNull("")
//         ^
//throws IllegalStateException: StringUtils.toNull("") must not be null
//try to assign a `null` from `toNull("")` to the non-nullable variable `value`
```

> **How** to avoiding such Exception throws by [kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/cfe159181d27d6bd085993d0ad70694a64081cd9/core/runtime.jvm/src/kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics.java)?

**IF** you are not sure that the **return value** whether is `null` or not from Java platform types, you should assign the value to a **nullable** variable/make the return type **nullable**, for example:

```
val value: String? = StringUtils.toNull("")
//         ^--- it works fine
```