# IllegalStateException: parcel.readString() must not be null

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin, parcelable

I put `Parcelable` object in `Intent` to next `Activity`:

```
val intent = Intent(mContext, ShowTestActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra("test", test)
Log.d("myLog", "${intent.getParcelableExtra<Test>("test")}") // No problem
mContext.startActivity(intent)
```

And get this object in next `Activity`:

```
if (!intent.hasExtra("test")) throw Exception("Intent doesn't has 'test' extra")
val test: Test = intent.getParcelableExtra("test")
```

And here are throwing Exception:

```
public open class QBase(): Parcelable {
  ...
  protected constructor(parcel: Parcel?) : this() {
      parcel?.let {
          question = parcel.readString() // parcel.readString() must not be null
          helpText = parcel.readString()
          qValue = parcel.readDouble()
          qType = QType.valueOf(parcel.readString())
      }
  }
  override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
      parcel.writeString(question)
      parcel.writeString(helpText)
      parcel.writeDouble(qValue)
      parcel.writeString(qType.name)
 }
  ...
}
```

And in Test:

```
public class Test(): Parcelable {
  ...
  public var questions: ArrayList<QBase> = ArrayList()

  constructor(parcel: Parcel?): this() {
      parcel?.let {
        ...
        parcel.readTypedList(questions, QBase.CREATOR)
      }
  }

  override fun writeToParcel(p: Parcel?, p1: Int) {
      p?.let {
          ...
          it.writeTypedList(questions)
      }
   }
   ...
}
```

It is an exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: parcel.readString() must not be null
>                                                                                      at com.vadim.hasdfa.justlearn.Model.Questions.utils.QBase.(QBase.kt:22)
>                                                                                      at com.vadim.hasdfa.justlearn.Model.Questions.utils.QBase$CREATOR.createFromParcel(QBase.kt:70)
>                                                                                      at com.vadim.hasdfa.justlearn.Model.Questions.utils.QBase$CREATOR.createFromParcel(QBase.kt:68)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Parcel.readTypedList(Parcel.java:2432)
>                                                                                      at com.vadim.hasdfa.justlearn.Model.Test.(Test.kt:28)
>                                                                                      at com.vadim.hasdfa.justlearn.Model.Test$CREATOR.createFromParcel(Test.kt:47)
>                                                                                      at com.vadim.hasdfa.justlearn.Model.Test$CREATOR.createFromParcel(Test.kt:45)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2787)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2681)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:3048)
>                                                                                      at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:257)
>                                                                                      at android.os.BaseBundle.containsKey(BaseBundle.java:435)
>                                                                                      at android.content.Intent.hasExtra(Intent.java:6859)
>                                                                                      at com.vadim.hasdfa.justlearn.Controller.Activity.BrowseTest.ShowTestActivity.onCreate(ShowTestActivity.kt:28)
>                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6980)
>                                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
>                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6540) 
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

Comment: You could add `Intent intent = getIntent();` in `ShowTestActivity` before you get object.

Comment: In kotlin `intent` means `getIntent()` in Java

Comment: oh,sorry for my poor in Kotlin.

Comment: Related:  [Kotlin call Java platform types result in llegalStateException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45127280/kotlin-call-java-platform-types-result-in-llegalstateexception/45128470#45128470)

Comment: Ok, I do it... And then all vars is null

Comment: @Hasdfa please update full QBase class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`question = parcel.readString() // parcel.readString() must not be null`

maybe the field `question` you defined is a not-null field, if the result of `parcel.readString()` returns a null value, there will be a `java.lang.IllegalStateException` throwed, just change the definition of `val question: String` into `val question: String?` and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45127280/kotlin-call-java-platform-types-result-in-llegalstateexception/45128470#45128470) -  For the time being, the only workaround is to make the member of the class that implements parcelable to be nullable.

Answer (score 0):

Because your string is null string, like question="null"